Rust borrow checker error in Observer pattern implementation
I am implementing the Observer pattern in Rust, but I'm encountering a panic due to a borrowing issue.
Here's a simplified version of my code:
pub trait Observer {
    fn update(&self);
}

pub trait Subject {
    fn add_observer(&mut self, observer: Rc<dyn Observer>);
    fn remove_observer(&mut self, observer: Rc<dyn Observer>);
    fn notify(&self);

    fn get_val(&self) -> &String;
}

pub struct ConcreteSubject {
    observers: Vec<Rc<dyn Observer>>,
    val: String,
}

impl ConcreteSubject {
    pub fn new() -> ConcreteSubject {
        ConcreteSubject { observers: Vec::new(), val: String::from("default") }
    }

    pub fn set_val(&mut self, new_val: String) {
        self.val = new_val;
        self.notify();
    }
}

impl Subject for ConcreteSubject {
    fn add_observer(&mut self, observer: Rc<dyn Observer>) {
        self.observers.push(observer);
    }

    fn remove_observer(&mut self, observer: Rc<dyn Observer>) {
        self.observers.retain(|x| !Rc::ptr_eq(x, &observer));
    }

    fn notify(&self) {
        self.observers
            .iter()
            .for_each(|x| x.update());
    }

    fn get_val(&self) -> &String {
        &self.val
    }
}


pub struct ConcreteObserver {
    subject: Rc<RefCell<dyn Subject>>,
    id: i32,
}

impl ConcreteObserver {
    pub fn new(mut subject: Rc<RefCell<dyn Subject>>) -> Rc<Self> {
        let observer = Rc::new(Self {
            subject: Rc::clone(&subject),
            id: random(),
        });

        println!("Observer created: {}", observer.id);

        subject
            .borrow_mut()
            .add_observer(Rc::clone(&observer) as Rc<dyn Observer>);

        observer
    }
}

impl Observer for ConcreteObserver {
    fn update(&self) {
        println!("Observer {} updated: {}",
                 self.id,
                 self.subject.borrow().get_val() // line 82
        );
    }
}


main function:
fn main() {
    let subject = Rc::new(RefCell::new(ConcreteSubject::new()));

    let observer1 = ConcreteObserver::new(Rc::clone(&subject) as Rc<RefCell<dyn Subject>>);
    let observer2 = ConcreteObserver::new(Rc::clone(&subject) as Rc<RefCell<dyn Subject>>);

    subject.borrow_mut().set_val(String::from("Hello"));
}

However, when I run the code, I get the following error:
thread 'main' panicked at 'already mutably borrowed: BorrowError', src/main.rs:xx
stack backtrace: (truncated)

It occurs when notify is called, which mutably borrows subject to update its observers, causing a panic. Here's the relevant part:
self.subject.borrow().get_val() // causes panic

I understand this is due to the multiple borrows happening during the notify call, but I'm unsure how to resolve it. I prefer to keep the pull model (where observers pull the data) instead of switching to a push model. How can I resolve this borrowing issue while maintaining the current design?

Can you add the lines numbers, or at least the important ones, so It's easy to follow the backtrace?
